# What is difference between openfeign/feign and spring cloud openfeign?

Tags: spring-cloud-feign, feign, openfeign

Could anyone describe what is difference between openfeign/feign and spring cloud openfeign? I see [spring cloud openfeign depends on openfeign/feign](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/blob/main/spring-cloud-openfeign-dependencies/pom.xml#L34), but I couldn't get specific differences.
Is it always recommendable to use spring cloud openfeign rather than vanilla feign when I use spring framework?

https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign

Answer (score 0):

OpenFeign/feign is a complete http client binder solution which can use multiple different libraries
[image: feign current features]

Spring Cloud Openfeign

> provides OpenFeign integrations for Spring Boot apps through
> autoconfiguration and binding to the Spring Environment and other
> Spring programming model idioms.

"Spring Cloud Openfeign" is only for spring, "OpenFeign" can work without **spring** environment.

Conclusion, if you are using spring go with "Spring Cloud Openfeign"

PS:https://youtu.be/3NcmlrumSOc this video explains with all details.