# Spring suggests to go ahead with Webclient instead of Rest Template (as eventually it will get deprecated), how would it affect Open Feign?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign, openfeign

With rest template eventually set for deprecation and Spring suggesting to use Webclient instead of rest template.

How will it affect Open Feign, will it also get deprecated?

Answer (score 1):

Everything will get deprecated eventually, like RestTemplate or before that we were using http client(it is not deprecated but no one uses it for REST anymore) for REST calls. Also OpenFeign looks like will stay long because it is a binder, you can use different clients underneath, so OpenFeign is kind of a higher abstraction layer, You can see further details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74748551/175554).